# Script stops working after replacing code by var name

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie and just started learning javascript. I have two almost the same scripts. This first one works fine, but I was wondering why the script stops working after replacing "document.getElementById("counter").value" by var name "getValue". Both contain the same code, right?

```
Counter: <input type="text" id="counter" value="0">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Increase</button>
```

1.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var getValue = document.getElementById("counter").value;
    ++document.getElementById("counter").value;
}
</script>
```

2.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var getValue = document.getElementById("counter").value;
    ++getValue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: getValue is local to that function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`++` assigns back to the value that its incrementing. When you declare `getValue`, thats a copy of the value that was in the `input`. It will need to be assigned back to the `.value` property somehow.

```
// given the value is "0"
function myFunction() {
    var getValue = document.getElementById("counter").value; // .value: "0"; getValue: "0"
    ++getValue; // .value "0"; getValue: 1
}
```

You can easily confirm this by logging to the console each step.

Notice that in your first script, `getValue` isn't even used.

Answer (score 0):

getValue is a variable and you have to assign the value back to the element. See the snippet.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var getValue = document.getElementById("counter").value;
    ++getValue;
    document.getElementById('counter').value=getValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="counter" value=0 />
<button onclick="myFunction();">+</button>
```